# Launching XCTest on Mac Catalyst fails with file not found error

Tags: xcode, mac-catalyst

I have an XCode Project which contains an iPhone/iPad app which I successfully ported over to mac using Mac Catalyst. When I try to launch my unit tests (written with XCTest). I get the following error:

```
The file “MyApp.app” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
NSFilePath = "/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-.../Build/Products/Debug/MyApp.app";
```

I've manually checked this path and indeed it doesn't exist. However there exists the folders

```
.../Products/Debug-maccatalyst
.../Products/Debug-iphoneos
```

I then modified the `Test Host`in MyAppTests' Build Settings to match the maccalyst folder and got the following error:

```
could not compute relative build path for TEST_HOST: PlugIns folder relative to $(TEST_HOST) 
is not a descendant of $(TARGET_BUILD_DIR) (/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-.../
Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst-maccatalyst/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp/../../PlugIns !<= 
/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-.../Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst)
```

What do I have to change to get the unit tests working on mac catalyst?